OpenFin window does not launch via Chromedriver (openFin version - 36.122.80.4, chromium version - 122.0.6261.69)
I am trying to upgrade my Java (jdk 11) Selenium (4) automation suite which is currently running fine for OpenFin v31.112.75.7 and Chromium v112.0.5615.28.
I want to upgrade it to OpenFin v36.122.80.4 (using chromium v122.0.6261.69 - as mentioned in documentation here - https://cdn.openfin.co/versions/#36.122.80.4)
The issue i am currently facing is:
On trying to launch openfin v36 (chromium v122) using the chromedriver, the window opens up is a blank window i.e. white blank window with no elements to interact with, hence the script fails while trying to login. When i try to print the title of the window handle, I get the title as 'openfin://blank'.
The issue I am facing is also mentioned as a known issue in documentation till openFin v35.120.79.7. I believe the issues are somewhat related, but not really sure.
For additional info, i am using below parameters in chromeoptions (selenium 4):
--disable-dev-shm-usage
--no-sandbox
--remote-debugging-port=9222
Headless
PLATFORM: any
BrowserVersion: 122.0.6261.69
I am looking for a solution to the problem of blank window appearing on launching openFin v36 via Chromedriver.
PS. I am running the tests on my local machine.
I tried explicit waits for the window to load but did not help.
